# .tpl шаблоны(PDO)

Tags: php, html, tpl

Делю сайт на .tpl шаблоны. Разделил на header.tpl, footer.tpl, и любой контент.tpl(пример: index.tpl или news.tpl). И там вместо определённых значений стоят %элементы_шаблона%. Так вот как все эти элементы заменить в переменные через ООП? Покажите пожалуйста пример, чтобы каждый элемент не пришлось заменять переменным.

Comment: в смысле обернуть? подключаешь, выводишь в шаблоне $node->title как пример в друпале

Comment: @Jean-Claude Сделать так, чтобы заменить %элементы% в перменные, при этом не делать каждый раз str_replace.

Comment: смотри выше, в друпале сделано так: `echo $node->title`, никаких реплейсов.

Comment: @Jean-Claude дело в том, что я не в Друпале работаю, не знаю что такое вообще `echo $node->title` и как ее использовать. Можете просвятить?

Comment: Любой курс Русакова скачайте он использует tpl шаблонизатор, и на ютубе валом уроков

Comment: Ersultan, а на что ты будешь заменять, скажем, %список_новостей%?

Comment: Почитайте код какого-нибудь шаблонизатора, например, Smarty - разберётесь, как это делается. Вам же не только переменные выводить, но и циклы. Иначе ответ будет слишком большим.

Comment: @AK Спасибо, того же Русакова я и читал. Просто не понял этот момент. Почитаю код twig.